# el path correcto de localhost

Tags: php

estoy guardando los archivos que sube el cliente para lo cual le defino la siguiente ruta1

```
 define('UPLOADS', 'http://wampserver/htdocs/uploads');
```

pero al guardar el archivo no encuentra esta ruta, por lo que la cambie por ruta2

```
define('UPLOADS', 'D:/wampserver/htdocs/uploads');
```

Ahi si graba y sube elarchivo correctamente, pero al momento de consultar no encuentra el archivo, pero si cambio a ruta1 para la consulta ahi si lo encuentra.

La plicacion esta en `htdocs/aplication` o sea al mismo nivel de `uploads`

No entiendo por que sucede. Gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar un archivo, el sistema necesita una ruta fisica donde hacer el store. Tu ruta http://wampserver/htdocs/uploads no es una ruta fisica, es una url.

Cuando vos le decis que guarde D:/wampserver/htdocs/uploads, tu servidor si conoce esa ruta y puede guardar fisicamente un archivo.

Ahora para leerlo es otra cosa. Depende de como lo estes leyendo, necesita o una ruta fisica, o una ruta de donde servirlo (por ejemplo, si lo pones como src de una imagen). Por eso en ese otro punto, tu ruta tiene que ser una url.

Comment: Lo que me dices es que debo tener dos rutas, una para subir y otra para leer? la  lectura la hago asi: `<img src="<?php echo UPLOADS;?>/products/<?php echo $grp_img;?>" />`

Comment: Exacto. Tu image se renderiza del lado del cliente y necesita acceder a la imagen a travez de una url publica. Php no puede guardar en una url, necesita una ruta fisica.

Comment: Bueno, es solo para el ambiente de desarrollo puesto que el servidor de produccion no tengo problema

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la ruta absouta debes usar la siguiente variable de servidor y de concatenar el subdirectorio:

```
define('UPLOADS', $_server['document_root']. '/uploads');
```

Comment: sirve para grabar no para leer!

Comment: Depende de como lo estes leyendo, pero prueba usando rutas relativas define('UPLOADS', '../../uploads');